# Symfony 2.4+ and simplesamlphp : NO STATE

Tags: php, symfony, saml, simplesamlphp

I tryed to implement SimpleSAMLPHP (https://simplesamlphp.org/) with Symfony 2.4+ (http://symfony.com/).
But since Symfony is managing the sessions, it destroy the SimpleSAML session before that one has been write.

Does anyone solve this problem ? I'm currently moving to another SAML library : onelogin/php-saml (https://github.com/onelogin/php-saml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally used php-saml from one-login, it works well.
I follow this tutorial : https://onelogin.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201175684-SAML-toolkit-for-PHP

Answer (score 0):

Out of the scope of the question: maybe you would like to share the implementation you did using Symfony2 and PHP-SAML?